# List all filesystems with a common label

Tags: filesystem

For various reasons, I have two partitions that both have a label of `root` on an embedded system I'm developing.

The `findfs` command only finds the first device with the label. Is there a way I can find all devices with the label?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `blkid` command instead:

```
blkid -o list -t LABEL=root
```

If you just want the partitions without extra info, use

```
blkid -o device -t LABEL=root
```

You may have to run the command as root (`sudo blkid`) the first time.